# Alternative return for javascript filter - Show message if client not found

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a searchbar on my angular2 application that returns the clients the user is looking for.
 This works fine but I want to show a message to the user when the client could'nt be found.

Im using `pipe` and `filter` to do it. Here's how the pipe looks like:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filtroPorNome'
})

export class FiltroPorNome implements PipeTransform{
    transform(disputas:any, digitado: string):any{
        digitado = digitado.toLowerCase();
        let disp_array = disputas.filter((disputa:any) => disputa.usuario.nome.toLowerCase().includes(digitado));
        if (disp_array.length === 0){
            return [-1]
        }else{
            return disp_array;
        }
    }
```

And this is the template where I implement the pipe:

```
        <input type="text" class="forms-econ" #textoProcurado (keyup)="0" placeholder="Procurar caso pelo nome do autor">
        <div *ngFor="let disputa of disputas | filtroPorNome: textoProcurado.value">
<div *ngIf="disputa === -1">"No matches"</div>
     <div *ngIf="disputa.status.status_nome == 'Atendimento Agendado'" class="col s12 m6 l4 xl3">
```

Can someone help me? All I need is some alternative return on the `pipe`so I can do validation on the template. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pipe can return some negative value like this if your is search list empty

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filtroPorNome'
})

export class FiltroPorNome implements PipeTransform{
    transform(disputas:any, digitado: string):any{
        digitado = digitado.toLowerCase();
        let result = disputas.filter((disputa:any) => disputa.usuario.nome.toLowerCase().includes(digitado));
         if(result.length === 0) {
      return [-1];
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

In your HTML you write some thing like this.

```
 <input type="text" class="forms-econ" #textoProcurado (keyup)="0" placeholder="Procurar caso pelo nome do autor">
<div *ngFor="let disputa of disputas | filtroPorNome: textoProcurado.value">
<div *ngIf="disputa === -1">"No matches"</div>
  <div *ngIf="disputa !== -1">{{ disputa }} </div>
  </div>
```

otherwise you can add pipe into another div with ngIF.

```
<div *ngIf="(disputas | filtroPorNome: textoProcurado.value).length === 0">
  "No matches"
</div>
```

this will execute Pipe two times ngIf and For loop.

Comment: I've tried your answer but I got some errors, the results are not being shown anymore, looks like it's always returnin `-1`. Im updating the question with the error and some more code. Thanks anyway

Comment: its always return "-1 "? put console.log and check result value in pipe

Comment: It's retuning length = 0. Before I put your code it used to show all clients and then the user could filter. Now it doens't show the clients and it keeps returning -1 :(

Comment: It's like the filter is not waiting the user type to activate it

Comment: try like this  <input type="text" class="forms-econ" #textoProcurado (keyup)="0"  [(ngModel)]="queryString" placeholder="Procurar caso pelo nome do autor">  <div *ngFor="let disputa of disputas | filtroPorNome: queryString">

Comment: weird, Im getting this error: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input', even though I already imported the FormsModule

Comment: man nevermind, you were right, I just forggot to duplicate this code on my page since I have three divs like the one above. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
let array = disputas.filter((disputa:any) => disputa.usuario.nome.toLowerCase().includes(digitado));
if(array.length === 0){
 array.push(new Disputa())
}
```

Set a fake disputa with a fake usuario